# why my code can't load any images?

Tags: android, picasso

here is my code to load image from server...what's wrong?
the app couldn't load any thing and show the force stop error.I removed parts of code that I'm sure thats work...

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private LayoutInflater myInflater;


    private List<String> labelIDs = new ArrayList<String>();

    private List<String> imageIDs = new ArrayList<String>();
    public void setData(List<String> values, List<String> images){
        this.labelIDs = values;
        this.imageIDs = images;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        ViewHolder holder;

        try {
            URL url = new URL("url"+imageIDs.get(position));
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());

            holder.ivIcon.setImageBitmap(bmp);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        holder.tvLabel.setText(labelIDs.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }   

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView ivIcon;
        TextView tvLabel;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean? That is correct. What is the error you are receiving?

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't know how can I replace context with the correct term?

you can use `this` or `YourActivityName.this` if you are subclassing `Activity`. you can use `getActivity()` if you are subclassing `Fragment`. If you are in a class where you don't have direct access to a Context object, you can either pass it or, in your case, you can use `holder.ivIcon.getContext()`.

Comment: but i couldn't load any image yet... .

Answer (score 0):

context represents the object of your Activity.Activity is inherited from Context Class.